# Why os.remove() raises exception PermissionError?

Tags: python, subprocess, readfile, named-pipes

On a Windows 7 platform I'm using python 3.6 as a framework to start working processes (written in C).
For starting the processes `subprocess.Popen` is used. The following shows the relevant code (one thread per process to be started).

```
redirstream = open(redirfilename, "w")
proc = subprocess.Popen(batchargs, shell=False, stdout=redirstream)
outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=60)

# wait for job to be finished
ret = proc.wait()

...

if ret == 0:  # changed !!
    redirstream.flush()
    redirstream.close()
    os.remove(redirfilename)
```

`communicate` is just used to be able, to terminate the executable after 60 seconds , for the case it hangs. `redirstream` is used to write output from the executable (written in C) to a file, used for general debugging purposes (not related to this issue). Of course, all processes are passed `redirfiles` with different filenames.

Up to ten such subprocesses are started in that way from independent python threads.

Although it works, I made a mysterious observation:

For the case an executable has finished without errors, I want to delete `redirfilename`, because it is not used anymore.

Now lets say, I have started process-A, B and C.

Processes A and B are finished and gave back 0 as result.
Process C however intentionally doesn't get data (just for testing, a serial connection has been disconnected) and waits for input from a named pipe (created from python) using Windows `ReadFile` function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx

In that case, while "C" is still waiting for `ReadFile` to be finished, os.remove(redirfilename) for A and B sometimes throws exception "`PermissionError`", saying, that the file is still used by another process. But from task manager I can see, that the processes A and B are not existing anymore (as expected).

I tried to catch the `PermissionError` and repeat the delete command after some delay. Only after "C" has terminated (timeout after 60 seconds), the redirfile for A or B can be deleted.

Why is the `redirstream` still blocked and somehow in use, although the process behind is not alive anymore and why is it blocked by `ReadFile()` in a completely unrelated process, **which is definitely not related** to that particular file? Is that an issue in Python or in my implementation?

Any hints are highly appreciated...

Comment: so you're not closing your output file when the process exits with success? this is highly fishy.

Comment: Hmmm. What output file do you mean ? It is closed in the if statement.

Comment: yes, if `ret` is not 0. Else it's not closed.

Comment: Sorry, I delete it when ret == 0 (no errors). The actual statement is a bit more complicated, and I made it more simple for my question. I changed it now to == in the question. So in summary: in my case ret=0, and I cannot delete it.

Comment: now you're not deleting it when there are errors... same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I close and delete it in a finally statement, which is not shown here. Anyway, even if I forgot this, it would not change the situation, because ret=0 for A and B, and C hangs. While C is still hanging, the exception occurs right in the if ret==1 clause.